# Javascript "Expect ;" on int

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, debugging

I keep getting "Expected ;"  error on the three int variables (month, day, year) I am defining:

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
  function validateDateFormat(input) 
  {
     var values = input.value.split("/");
     int month = parseInt(values[0]);
     int day =   parseInt(values[1]);
     int year =  parseInt(values[2]);

     if ((month < 1 || month > 12)) 
     {
       alert("Month value: "+ month + " is not a valid month using MM/DD/YYYY format");
       input.value = "";
       return;
     }

     if ((String.valueOf(year).length() != 4)) 
     {
       alert("Year value: "+ year + " is not a valid year using MM/DD/YYYY format");
       input.value = "";
       return;
     }

     if(day < 1 || day > daysInMonth(month, year))
     {
       alert("Day value: "+ day + " is not a valid day for the month with value: " + month + " using MM/DD/YYYY format");
       input.value = "";
       return;
     }
   };
```

....

When I try to run the page the debugger in FireFox throws:

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

I don't understand what the problem is. Even if I just do, int month = 0 as the first line, I still get the same error.  I am using this with Razor on Asp.net MVC 4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't declare a variable as `int` in javascript.

Change

```
int month = parseInt(values[0]);
```

to

```
var month = parseInt(values[0]);
```

(and of course do it for the two following lines too)

If you really want typed variables you could have a look at TypeScript but I'd strongly suggest you to dive into idiomatic JS first.

Comment: Then do the same for `day` and `month` too

Comment: Ah that fixed it.   Thanks all. Just a lack of experience with JavaScript.

Comment: Random advice: avoid putting the opening curly brace on its own line in JS. You'll prevent strange bugs...